# Not getting data in predefined Datagrid columns

Tags: c#, datagrid

I have a predefined datagrid columns which loads on form loading.What I wanted was when I enter id or name of product in the text box I wanted it to display in the datagrid columns.But when I enter Id or product name nothing gets displayed in the columns.I've tried the followong code:

```
   public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        load();
    }
    void load()
    {
        string cc = "";
        int n;
        if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out n))
        {
            cc = "product_Id = " + textBox1.Text.Trim();
        }
        else
        {
            cc = "product_Name LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "%'";
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        {
            cc = "1 = 1";
        }

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SUMIT;Initial Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=True");

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select product_Name as [Product Name],cast(actual_Sp as INT) * '" + textBox2.Text + " 'as [Actual SP] from Product WHERE " + cc, con); ;

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 7;

        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "ProductId";
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "PID";
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "product_Id";

        dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "S.N.";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Serial Number";
        // dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "ContactName";

        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Particulars";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Particulars";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "product_Name";


        dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "Unit Quantity";
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Unit Quantity";
        //dataGridView1.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "product_Name";


        dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "Amount";
        dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Amount";
        // dataGridView1.Columns[4].DataPropertyName = "product_Name";


        dataGridView1.Columns[5].Name = "Discount";
        dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Discount";
        //dataGridView1.Columns[5].DataPropertyName = "product_Name";


        dataGridView1.Columns[6].Name = "Sub-Total";
        dataGridView1.Columns[6].HeaderText = "Sub-Total";
        // dataGridView1.Columns[6].DataPropertyName = "product_Name";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    }
```

Comment: I think you are using WinForms and not WPF. Plz check proper tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL query returns a table with columns `Product Name` and `Actual SP` but in your `datagridview` you are assigning ;

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "product_Id";
```

but `product_Id` column is not in your data table.

Change as follows;

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Actual SP";
dataGridView1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "Product Name";
```

Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You must add each column to the DataGridView like:

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("ProductId","PID");
dataGridView1.Columns["ProductId"].DataPropertyName="product_Id";
```